# Interaction picture field operators, and the on-shell condition

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In the explicit expression of the interaction picture field operator in terms of ladder operators given in Peskin and Schroeder (4.15), the time-dependence is specified via an instruction to evaluate the expression at $x_0 = t-t_0$,

\begin{align}
\phi_I(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p}}} \left( a_{\vec{p}}e^{-ip\cdot x} + a_{\vec{p}}^\dagger e^{ip\cdot x}\right)\bigg|_{x_0 = t-t_0}. \tag{4.15}
\end{align}

In this expression, the value of $p_0$ is always equal to $E_\vec{p}$, but this fact is left implicit within the four-vector $p$ appearing in each exponent. Is that right? I could make it explicit by writing,

\begin{align}
\phi_I(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p}}} \left( a_{\vec{p}}e^{-ip\cdot x} + a_{\vec{p}}^\dagger e^{ip\cdot x}\right)\bigg|_{x_0 = t-t_0; p_0 = E_{\vec{p}}},
\end{align}

correct? It's an operator defined by an integration over all three-momenta, or equivalently, an integration over all on-shell four momenta.